# Mysql - Combine two tables with different date value with group by

Tags: mysql, union, outer-join

I'm working on project, 
Where i need to show earned points and exchanged points by user per day.

I have two different table to store data. `tables(a,b)` are as below:
**table a:**

```
id   user_id     earned   created_at
--------------------------------------------
1      1          1       2016-12-14
2      2          2       2016-12-14
3      2          1       2016-12-14
4      3          1       2016-12-15
```

**table b:**

```
id   user_id   exchanged   created_at
--------------------------------------------
1      1          1       2016-12-14
2      1          2       2016-12-14
3      2          1       2016-12-14
4      4          1       2016-12-15
5      3          3       2016-12-16
```

I want to merge both tables on date as below

```
user_id     earned  exchanged    created_at
-------------------------------------------------
  1          1           1        2016-12-14
  2          3           1        2016-12-14
  3          1           0        2016-12-15
  4          0           1        2016-12-15
  3          0           3        2016-12-16
```

I've tried searching SO, I end up with below query ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3383/3)):

```
select user_id, created_at, sum(earned) as earned, sum(exchanged) as exchanged from (
SELECT 
    a.user_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%d-%m-%Y') AS created_at,
    a.earned,
    0 AS exchanged
FROM
    a
        LEFT JOIN
    b ON DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%y%m%d') = DATE_FORMAT(b.created_at, '%y%m%d') 
UNION SELECT 
    b.user_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(b.created_at, '%d-%m-%Y') AS created_at,
    0 AS earned,
    b.exchanged
FROM
    a
        RIGHT JOIN
    b ON DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%y%m%d') = DATE_FORMAT(b.created_at, '%y%m%d')
    ) as tbl group by tbl.created_at, tbl.user_id
```

But it shows incorrect sum of exchanged points.

Comment: You need to change order of group by columns to "group by tbl.user_id, tbl.created_at"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```sql
select user_id, created_at, sum(earned), sum(exchanged) from
((select id, user_id, earned, 0 as exchanged, created_at from a)
union all 
(select id, user_id, 0 as earned, exchanged, created_at from b)) combined
group by user_id, created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: this query will fetch results only if there are entries in both the tables for per user per day.

```
select ex.user_id, ex.created_at, sum(earned) as earned, sum(exchanged) as exchanged 
from exchanged ex, earned ea 
where ea.created_at = ex.created_at 
and ea.user_id = ex.user_id 
group by user_id, created_at
```

Comment: By joining these two tables one will lose entries where a particular user at a particular day has either an earned-entry or an exchanged-entry but not both. That's why the query referenced by Ravi implements a full outer join (by combining a left join and a right join)